# Python list that want the sum of list excluding a value range from number in the list to another number, in this case 6 to 9

Tags: python

suppose in a python list:

```
l1 = [2,5,21,6,8,5,9,8,12]
```

here I want the sum of list excluding the value from `6` to `9` i.e. `2+5+21+8+12`, I want the value from `6` to `9` i.e. `6,8,5,9` to get omitted.

here in the list the number 6 is at index 3 and number 9 is at index 6, so i want those values to be exclude

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Are you excluding based on index or based on entry/exit values?

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(l1) - sum(l1[l1.index(6):l1.index(9) + 1])
```

Note that if you had two or more occurrences of 6 or 9 in your list, this would exclude the range between the FIRST occurrences

Comment: is there any way to solve the problem of two or more occurrence of 6 or 9

Comment: You would have to specify which occurrence you wanted to be the start or end of your excluded range  - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267241/how-to-find-the-index-of-the-nth-time-an-item-appears-in-a-list for how to get the index in that case

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to sum all numbers in `l1` but those included in `[6,9]`, you could use list comprehension with an `if` for your inclusion constraint and then sum the obtained list:

`sum([n for n in l1 if n not in range(6,9+1)])`

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).