# Index values of repeating elements of a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, repeat

I saw this solution in another post [Index of duplicates items in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list/5419248#5419248) , where it is made clear that using the below code, you can get the index positions of repeating elements in a list.

[[], [], [], [], [], [], 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 6, 1, 7, 6, 1, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0]

```
def duplicates(lst, item):
       return [j for j, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]
print(duplicates(XORcomb, 2)))
```

***OUTPUT***

[6, 29, 30]

However, if i try to iterate the process, it doesn't work.

```
N = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    

def duplicates(lst, item):
     return [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]

for each in N:
     print("%r occurs at: %r " %(each, duplicates(XORcomb, each)))
```

***OUTPUT***

'1' occurs at: []

'2' occurs at: []

'3' occurs at: []

'4' occurs at: []

'5' occurs at: []

It works fine if list N is pre-defined. But if list N is user-defined, then it doesn't work.

```
n = int(input("Enter number of values: ")) #Get user input for no. of values
N = []
for e in range (1, n+1):
     elements = input("Enter element %r: " %e)
     N.append(elements)
XORcomb = [[], [], [], [], [], [], 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 6, 1, 7, 6, 1, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0]
def duplicates(lst, item):
     return [j for j, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]
for each in N:
     print("%r occurs at: %r " %(each, duplicates(XORcomb, each)))
```

Comment: You are calling the function for each individual element. It is just printing the element, then an empty list, since it is not possible to have a duplicate with only one element.

Comment: Try printing `XORcomb` maybe it no longer has `1` or `2` or so.

Comment: I get an entirely other result if I use the list above in `XORComb`, could you check that `XORComb` is what you think it is?

Comment: XORcomb = [[], [], [], [], [], [], 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 6, 1, 7, 6, 1, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0]

Comment: XORcomb hasn't changed

Comment: can you show the complete code you are using? How is XORcomb defined?

Comment: Anand S Kumar, I just edited my post. You'll find the code there (the complete code is too long, so only the relevant lines for this question)

Comment: My output is exactly the same as elegent's. If you want an answer please provide an example (including output/input) that fails that we can reproduce.

Comment: the example is given in the final code above. Try giving no. of values as 5, and the elements as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I need to search for the elements input to N (user-defined).

Comment: @skyking it works. check the comments below.....thank you

Comment: I still get the same result as elegent below (if that's is not the result that you'd expect you'll have to explain why). If your code on the other hand results in the expected result - I don't really understand what the question is.

Comment: if you see above, i didn't convert elements into integer before appending to list N.....which resulted in not producing an output. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **`input()` returns a string** not a number. When you run your `duplicates()` function **you compare integers and strings** and get an empty result, because there are no stringgs in your `XORcomb` list.

You need to convert it using `int()` before adding it to `N` as you used did for `n`:

```
>>> XORcomb = [None, None, None, None, None, None, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                  3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 6, 1, 7, 6, 1, 1,
                  5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0]
>>> N = []
>>> n = int(input("Enter number of values: "))

>>> for e in range(0, n):
       element = input("Enter element {}: ".format(str(e + 1)))
       N.append(int(element))


>>> for each in N:
     print("%r occurs at: %r " %(each, duplicates(XORcomb, each)))


1 occurs at: [16, 21, 24, 25] 
2 occurs at: [6, 29, 30] 
3 occurs at: [7, 10, 28] 
4 occurs at: [8, 11, 13, 27] 
5 occurs at: [9, 12, 14, 15, 26]
```

Comment: yes, i have tried this and it works. But, the problem is that XORcomb varies with list N. So, i need to use the elements of list N (input from user)

Comment: No it doesn't. It gives the output as stated in my question, above.

Comment: When I run your code its working (`for each in N:`...)

Comment: Its recognizing each element of the list, doesn't find the index values

Comment: can you paste your output please?

Comment: I need to search for values in list N, not from 1 to n

Comment: @VinodRanganath: Yes sorry was a  typo You are right of course! Does it work now?

Comment: It was because of N.append(int(elements))

Comment: @VinodRanganath: If you want you can except this answer :)