# PERL Put the same index to duplicate words. (first time seen word index)

Tags: arrays, perl, list, hash

I have like a month with this problem. I want to check in my file all the words.

`EXAMPLE FILE:_word [0] word1 [1] word1 [2] word2 [3] _word [4]`

That will be the positions, but i want that if i see the word:_word in the position 0, put that position 0 to the word in the position 4 that is the same ("_word") duplicate.

I have try a lot with this problem.

I want to do something like this:

`EXAMPLE :_word [0] word1 [1] word1 [1] word2 [2] _word [0]`

The [number] are the positions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your description is really confusing, and I might be able to understand the problem better if I see the code you've attempted to write.

Comment: It's still not clear. that's a similar question, but it is different. And for another programming language. What have you tried so far. Can you put your `EXAMPLE` outside of the codeblock and show exactly what you expect the input and the output to be?

Comment: Ok, for example in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list

I have a list List = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E']; 

I want to get something like this:
index 0: A   
index 2: A  but in here instead of the 2, put 0 again..because its the same word...

Comment: So, since there's no code, can I assume you haven't tried anything yet? Are you looking for help with the algorithm?

Comment: It sounds like you want to remove all duplicate elements except the first from an array, e.g. `('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B')` -> `('A', 'B', 'C')`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, given the string `"_word word1 word1 word2 _word"`, you want to come up with the array `(0,1,1,3,0)` -- for the first index of each word, then you could do:

```
$line = "_word word1 word1 word2 _word";
@words = split " ", $line;
$first_index{$words[$_]} //= $_ for 0..$#words;
push @indices, $first_index{$_} for @words;
```