# Finding all indexes of a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I searched the forums and tried a couple of the answers but it does not seem to work for me.

So my problem is I have a list of lists which has 0 and 'M' in at different places every time you run the program.The position of the 'M' is randomized.

So I wanna get the indexes of all the positions of where the 'M' is in the list.

I have tried this:

```
hiddenfield =  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M'],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 'M', 'M'],
                [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M'],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 'M', 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 'M', 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                ['M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0]] 

position_of_m = []

for i in hiddenfield:
        position_of_m.append(i.index('M'))
print(position_of_m)
```

and all i get is the first index of all of the lists like this:

```
[5, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0]
```

how do i solve this?

EDIT:

Ok guys so i got some help from you earlier. But right now i am banging my head against the table.

The code works 'kinda'. But i don't want the last numbers of the list to add to the first number of another list. Hard for me to explain so i´ll show you further down!

heres the code:

```
hiddenfield =  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M'],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M', 'M', 'M'],
            [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M'],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 'M', 0, 0, 0],
            ['M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 'M', 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M'],
            ['M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0]] 



def update_numbers(x, y, hiddenfield):
try:
    if hiddenfield[x][y] != 'M':
        hiddenfield[x][y] += 1
except IndexError:
    pass

def numbersinhiddefield(indexes):
indexes = [[i,j] for i,row in enumerate(indexes) for j,elem in enumerate(row) if elem == 'M']
loop = 0
while loop < len(indexes):
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]+1,indexes[loop][1], hiddenfield)
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]-1,indexes[loop][1], hiddenfield)
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0],indexes[loop][1]+1, hiddenfield)
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0],indexes[loop][1]-1, hiddenfield)
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]+1,indexes[loop][1]+1, hiddenfield)
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]-1,indexes[loop][1]-1, hiddenfield)
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]+1,indexes[loop][1]-1, hiddenfield)
    update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]-1,indexes[loop][1]+1, hiddenfield)
    loop += 1


def showMineFieldHidden(hiddenfield):
border = list(range(0,len(hiddenfield)))
row = [' ']+border
i = 0
for rows in [border]+hiddenfield:
    print(row[i], end=' ')
    i += 1
    for lines in rows:
        print(lines, end=' ')
    print()

numbersinhiddefield(hiddenfield)

showMineFieldHidden(hiddenfield)
```

But the thing i get out isn't just right:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 0 0 1 1 2 M 2 2 4 M 
1 0 1 2 M 3 2 3 M M M 
2 0 1 M 4 M 2 2 M 5 M 
3 0 2 2 5 M 3 1 1 2 1 
4 0 1 M 4 M 4 2 1 0 0 
5 1 2 3 M 4 M M 2 1 1 
6 M 1 3 M 4 2 3 M 1 1 
7 2 3 4 M 3 1 1 1 2 2 
8 2 M M 4 M 1 0 1 2 M 
9 M 3 3 M 3 2 1 1 M 4 <-- this is supposed to be a 2.
            ^
            this is supposed to be a 1 and the one next to it a zero
```

I think it is adding from the borders to the lower list?

Would appreciate som help!

Comment: Also possibly see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[(i,j) for i,row in enumerate(hiddenfield) for j,elem in enumerate(row) if elem == 'M']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = []

for i in hiddenfield:
    start = 0
    for _ in range(i.count('M')):
        k = i.index('M',start)
        m.append(k)
        start = k
```