# Python: Counting a list and displaying a range of the count

Tags: python

So I have a list with two numbers which are 1 and 0. Each item in list is equivalent to 1 second of audio. 0 is speech while 1 is music.

Example of the list:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I want the output to display the start of audio, end of audio and the type of audio.

Output:

```
1,6,    music 
7,12,   speech
13,17,  music
18,24,  speech
25,26,  music
27,32,  speech
33,37,  music
```

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Look at the second part of highest voted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list) page. It does "similar" to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[2]: data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
In[3]: from itertools import groupby
  ...: 
  ...: dex = 1
  ...: result = []
  ...: for k, g in groupby(data):
  ...:     length = sum(1 for _ in g)
  ...:     result.append((
  ...:         (dex, dex + length - 1),
  ...:         'music' if k == 1 else 'speech'
  ...:     ))
  ...:     dex += length
  ...: 
In[4]: result
Out[4]: 
[((1, 6), 'music'),
 ((7, 12), 'speech'),
 ((13, 17), 'music'),
 ((18, 24), 'speech'),
 ((25, 26), 'music'),
 ((27, 32), 'speech'),
 ((33, 37), 'music')]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is exactly what I wanted the output to look like. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
changes = [i+1 for i,val in enumerate(a[:-1]) if val != a[i+1]]
lists_start_end = [(1,changes[0])] + [(val+1,changes[i+1]) for i,val in enumerate(changes[:-1])] + [(changes[-1],len(a))]
```

Out:

```
[(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 17), (18, 24), (25, 26), (27, 32), (32, 37)]
```