# Tuple fails to print index if the item is repeated more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am learning Python3 and I'm in tuples chapter now.

While we can use index method to print the place of an item like this:

```
>>> tup = ('a','b','a','c')
>>> tup.index('c')
>>> 3
```

But when I try to print the index for repeated item, it only prints for the first item and simply ignore the second one.

```
>>> tup.index('a')
    0
```

I am expecting tuple to print both index (location).

Expected output

```
>>> tup.index('a')
    0, 2
```

May I know why tuple having this behaviour? what if if we want to print the index for the repeated item in the tuple?

Comment: not only **tuple**, any sequence will return the first catch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index of duplicates items in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's what `tuple.index` does:

```
>>> help(tup.index)
index(...)
    T.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
```

If you want all indices, you can make a list comprehension:

```
indices = [i for i, val in enumerate(tup) if val == 'c']
```

Answer (score 5):

`tuple.index` is actually a three-argument function: `tuple.index(x, start, end)`. It finds the *first* element equal to `x` in the range `tuple[start:end]`. It's just that by default `start = 0` and `end = len(t)`.

If you want the index of the second element you can do:

```
>>> i = tup.index('a')
>>> tup.index('a', i + 1)
2
```

If you want all indices you can use a list comprehension like L3viathan suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `numpy.argwhere`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html

```
import numpy as np

np.argwhere(tup == 'a')
```