# Exchanging second appearance of string in list to 0 using python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to set the second appearance of a text in a list to 0. The first appearance of the word should remain untouched.

e.g.

```py
Xlist=["dog", "cat", "horse", "dog"]
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
["dog", "cat", "horse", "0"]
```

Is there a simple way to do it? Since I'm new to python programming I can't really imagine how to do it and I didn't find a way in other threads.

Comment: Find [indices of dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419204/4636715) and set the values of those indices to `0` (except the first item which you want to keep in your case)

Comment: What about third appearance of an element? Should only 2nd appearance be set to 0?

Comment: This problem is not very well defined. What should happen to this list: `["dog", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "horse"]`?

Comment: Looks like an exercise. Please provide what you have tried, why it isn't working, etc.
[Help-Center: how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The answer @jaswanth has provided already solved my problem. Every appearance after the 2nd should be changed to "0". Sorry if that was misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
keys = set([])
for index, item in enumerate(data):
    if item in keys:
        data[index] = "0"
        continue
    keys.add(item)

print(data)
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: I would recommend to use `set` data type for `keys` instead of a `list`.

Comment: Thanks, for people who did not understand It is better because the time complexity of searching in a set is less compared to a list that is why it is better to use `set` instead of `list`. edited the solution