# How do I find each duplicate's index in a List in Python?

Tags: python, list

For example, let's say I have a list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6]
```

Is there any function that returns all the indexes of the 3s?(which would return [2, 3, 5])

Comment: This answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list

Comment: What is the result for `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6,6,6,6]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index of duplicates items in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the list in order to build a dictionary of all items that appeared more than once.

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6]

# only values that appears more than once
c = Counter(lst) - Counter(set(lst))

res = {}
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if elem in c:
        item = res.get(elem)
        if item:
            item.append(i)
        else:
            res[elem] = [i]

print(res)
```

output :

```
{2: [1, 7], 3: [2, 3, 5]}
```

A better approach is to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) :

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6]

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    d[elem].append(i)

print({k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1})
```

output :

```
{2: [1, 7], 3: [2, 3, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use function enumerate(lst)
it returns elements index_number and value.
for example

```
lst[0] = 1
```

the case above index_number is 0
and value is 1

so you can just use enumerate function for returning index number using if condition
(returns it when the value is 3)

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6]
lst_result = [i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v == 3]
print(lst_result)
```

**your outcome will be**

```
[2,3,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out a solution for a similar problem and this is what I came up with.

```
def locate_index(item_name, list_name):
    """Determine the indexes of an item if in a list."""
    locations = []
    for i in range(len(list_name)):
        if list_name[i] == item_name:
            locations.append(list_name.index(item_name, i, len(list_name)))
    print(locations)
```

Example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]

locate_index(3, lst)     ---- a)
locate_index(6, list2)   ---- b)
```

Output

```
a)
[2, 3, 5]

b)
[7, 8, 9, 10]
```