# Get all indexes for duplicate elements in a list

Tags: python

How would you get all indexes of the duplicate items as well as the unique items from a list and put it into a dictionary.
I want to write a code that doesn’t use the enumerate function and set function as shown below

```
 x = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]

 Dictionary = {}

 for i in set(x):

 if x.count(i) > 1:
   Dictionary[i] = [str(index) for index, value in enumerate(x) if value == i]
 Print(Dictionary)
```

I hope to get an output as follows:

```
{1.2:[0,6],2.4:[1],3.1:[2,7]...}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use set and enumerate?

Comment: List= {} declares a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list ... Note that this is a dictionary, so it might need some adaptations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index of duplicates items in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list)

Comment: You literally just need to wrap the return vale of `list_duplicates` with a `dict` call in the top voted answer in the link above...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but you certainly can.

```py
x = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]

uniqueItems = []
duplicateIndexes = []
counter = 0

for num in x:
    if num not in uniqueItems:
        uniqueItems.append(num)
    else:
        duplicateIndexes.append(counter)
    counter += 1

print(uniqueItems)
print(duplicateIndexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works! You need to import the collections module and use the Counter class. I didn't use the enumerate or set functions just as the OP requested.

```
import collections

x = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]
new_dict = {}
counter = collections.Counter(x)
elements = [i for i in counter] 
for elem in elements:
    new_dict[elem]=[i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i]==elem]

print(new_dict)
```

Output is the dictionary `{1.2: [0, 6], 2.4: [1], 3.1: [2, 7], 4.0: [3], 5.6: [4], 6.5: [5], 8.1: [8], 23.6: [9], 29.3: [10]}`

Answer (score -1):

Using generator expressions and comprehensions this is pretty straightforward.

First let's get all values that appear more than once in a `set`.

```
x = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.0, 5.6, 6.5, 1.2, 3.1, 8.1, 23.6, 29.3]

multiples = set(a for a in set(x) if x.count(a) > 1)
```

Now, to get the indexes, we can use `enumerate` and a list comprehension to only collect indexes for values that are in `multiples`.

```
[i for i, a in enumerate(x) if a in multiples]
```

And the output is:

```
[0, 2, 6, 7]
```