# Finding the actuall index of an repeated element in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, append

I am trying to find the capital letters in a word and append their indexes in new list

eg:

```
Input           Output
pYtHoN          [1, 3, 5]
CApiTAls    [0, 1, 4, 5]
```

I created new list containing all the letters and checked if they are capital or not and append the result in a new list:

```
word = input()
word_list = list(word)

upper_case_list = []
for letter in word_list:
    if letter == letter.upper():
        upper_case_list.append(word_list.index(letter))

print(upper_case_list)
```

But my output is:

```
CApiTAls
[0, 1, 4, 1]
```

My output gives me the index 1 instead index 5:

```
['C', 'A', 'p', 'i', 'T', 'A', 'l', 's']
```

How can I get the actual index of A at index 5 and not repeated index 1?

Note: Im self-teaching to programming, also new.

Comment: Why use `.index` to find the index of the character? You're iterating over the string, you already know the index. Use `enumerate`

Comment: Alternatively, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list

Comment: Note also that you don't need to turn `word` into a list - you can already iterate over a string

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` to access the index while iterating. (`list.index` will only return the first index of an element.)

```py
for index, letter in enumerate(word_list):
    if letter.isupper():
        upper_case_list.append(index)
```

Or, with a list comprehension:

```py
upper_case_list = [index for index, letter in enumerate(word_list) if letter.isupper()]
```